# Does Silverlight require the .NET framework to be installed?

Tags: .net, silverlight

I have been exploring the possibilities of Microsoft Silverlight and how it runs in web browsers. I just wonder if Silverlight requires the .NET framework? Meaning that Mac or Linux users cannot run Silverlight. I will be making the application using the .NET framework 3.5. Will this application run in any web browser, or just major ones like Internet Explorer, Firefox, or Safari?

Comment: The brilliant minds at stackoverflow will help you to solve this terrible mystery. If only Microsoft would post such basic information about its major technologies! Oh, woe! Oh, wait... http://www.microsoft.com/silverlight/faq/

Comment: To answer the question clearly: NO .NET framework requirement. And Ben, yeah I agree, it's hard to find that kind of info.. too many sub-sites.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the **[matrix of supported browsers and operating systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silverlight#Operating_systems_and_web_browsers)** for Silverlight.  As you can see there, Silverlight has fairly wide support, with obvious neglect in Linux.

Only the plugin is needed.

Answer (score 2):

All you need is the Silverligh plugin appropiate for your operative system

http://www.microsoft.com/getsilverlight/Get-Started/Install/Default.aspx

Comment: Do most web browsers have this plugin?

Comment: On the link I pasted check the tab "System Requirements". There you have all supported OP and browsers

Answer (score 1):

Silverlight runs on mac, and linux too I think, so I'm guessing it doesn't need .NET to run

Answer (score -1):

It's yes and no, on the surface it doesn't require .NET framework installation but inside it there is bundled minimal .NET CLR runtime just enough to make silverlight works. Afterall SL is a Managed technology with performance sensitive part as native code.

On windows, part of its SL install there is files such as:

```
coreclr.dll
mscorlib.dll
```

on mac there is

```
CoreCLR.bundle
```

in other word, microsoft ported minimal .NET framework to supported platforms.